# Oracle APEX: Get Facebook User Token?

Tags: oracle, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oracle-apex

I'm trying to send some REST commands from Oracle APEX to Facebook Graph API to get the user token.

Here is my code :

```
    ServerURL := 'http://MyReverseProxy/graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';

    RedirectURL := 'http://www.example.com';
    ApplicationID := 'xxxx';
    ApplicationPassword := 'yyyy';

    Command := ServerURL || '?client_id=' || ApplicationID || '&redirect_uri=' || RedirectURL || '&client_secret=' || ApplicationPassword || '&default_graph_version=v2.4';

    Method := 'GET';

    Response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => Command, p_http_method => Method);
```

The code doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Proxy Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Proxy Error</h1>
        <p>
        The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.<br />
        The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/oauth/access_token">GET"
        </p>

        /graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token</a></em>.
        <p>
        Reason: 
        <strong>DNS lookup failure for: graph.facebook.comoauth</strong>
        </p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: `DNS lookup failure for: graph.facebook.comoauth` ... that sounds like an issue with your proxy, and not one with Facebook to begin with. Somehow it has mangled the host name and URL path of the request together ...

Comment: And btw., that request is not for generating a _user_ access token, but only an _app_ access token (and the latter you could have easier, by combining app id and secret with a pipe symbol in the middle.)